# JQuery Autocomplete function on combined field asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, spell-checking

I have a class that creates a recipe line.

```
 public class RecipeLine
    {
        [Key]
        public int RecipeLineId { get; set; }

        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }    
        public virtual UnitOfMeasureModel UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
        public virtual IngredientModel Ingredient { get; set; }

        public string QuantityUomIngredient => $"{Quantity} {UnitOfMeasure?.Abbreviation ?? ""} {Ingredient?.Name ?? ""}";
    }
```

public string QuantityUOMIngredient is used to fill the database, and a custom binder is created to populate the seperate fields.

When entering information into the input field on the website for QuantityUOMIngredient, there should be an autocomplete function. I have read about jquery but I am not entirely sure how to solve this.

The line will look like this
i.e.   1 kg potatoes

On the "1" there will only be a validation.

After pressing the spacebar and entering a "k", we should see an autocomplete dropdown with all the possiblities for "k".

Again after entering a spacebar and entering a "p" there should be an autocomplete dropdown for the ingredient.

It should also be possible to autocomplete with minor misspellings in the string. i.e. when someone would enter "poto", then the autocomplete dropdown should show "potato".

Thanks in advance.